# Oracle Enterprise Manager Export to Network Drive

Tags: database, oracle, export, database-backups

I am trying to export tables from my database via OEM. I would like to export the tables to a network drive.

The network drive is mounted and I am able access it on my desktop. I have tested that export works to my C:\ drive.

When I try to create a directory to export to the network drive I get this message: "The directory X:\ does not exist". If I use C:\ I get "The directory C:\ exist" (yeah, they should have made that exists).

Does anyone know why OEM will not recognize the network drive? Or some way of getting this directory set up so OEM will recognize it?

Thanks in advance awesome smart programmers!

Answer (score 0):

I think that in order to do this you need to use an OS account that is a domain user when you specify the OS user to enterprise manager. I've run into the same issue cloning a database from one machine to another.

Answer (score 0):

It looks, most likely, to be an issue with the way directory is created and granted access.

Make sure oracle directory (not OS directory) is created properly and granted access as per following (for ref):-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DMPDIR AS 'C:\DUMP';

GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY DMPDIR TO SCOTT;
```

Change name 'DMPDIR' & path 'C:\DUMP' as per your local env.

You can try it outside of OEM using expdp (datapump) to ascertain if the issue with OEM or with the way you are using/creating directory.

HTH